# C++ Function Pointers. How and why it works?

Tags: c++

Consider following programme

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <class T>
void Output(const char * Str, T Func)
   {
      void *Ptr = reinterpret_cast<void *>(Func);
      std::ptrdiff_t Num = reinterpret_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(Ptr);
      std::cout << Str << " " << Num << std::endl;
   }

class TAnotherBase  { long a[10]; };

struct TBase {
      typedef void (TBase::*TFunc)();
      TFunc Func;
      TBase(TFunc F) {
            Func = F;
            Output("Ctor TBase ", Func);
         }
      void CallF() {
            std::cout << "This in TBase: " << typeid(this).name() << " " << this << std::endl;
            (this->*Func)();
         }
   };

struct TDerived: public TAnotherBase, public TBase {
      TDerived(): TBase(static_cast<TBase::TFunc>(&TDerived::F)) {
            Output("Ctor TDerived ", &TDerived::F);
            CallF();
         }
      void F() {
            std::cout << "This in TDerived::F: " <<typeid(this).name() << " " << this << std::endl;
         }
   };

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
      TDerived Derived;
      return 0;
   }
```

It generates this output:

```
Ctor TBase  4197502                                (1)
Ctor TDerived  4197502                             (2)
This in base: P5TBase 0x7fff6b30fc00               (3)
This in TDerived::F: P8TDerived 0x7fff6b30fbb0     (4)
```

What is going on here

I have function `F` in `TDerived` class, then I send pointer to the function to `TBase` class: `TDerived(): TBase(static_cast<TBase::TFunc>(&TDerived::F)) {` and (1) output  function pointer.
Then I output function pointer in `TDerived` class (2) and make `TBase` class to call the function: `CallF(); (4), (5).

`TAnotherBase` is here to make different `this` pointers of `TBase` and `TDerived` classes.

So, first question.

I read that function pointers is more like offsets relative to `this`. If so, why I get the same function pointer values in (1) and (2) - 4197502 ?

Second question

I output `this` in `CallF` function (3) and it is all right. But then I call function `(this->*Func)();` via `this` (which is `TBase`) and in function `F` `this` magically becomes completely different `this` (4)! It changes its type and value! How it is possible? How compiler still remembers that `Func` (which type is `typedef void (TBase::*TFunc)();`) is actually from `TDerived` class? How compiler knows that it should adjust `this` before sending it to `F`? Why and how it works?

Comment: "I read that function pointers is more like offsets relative to this." this is misleading on its own. Where did you read this? That said, your static_cast is probably causing UB, so all bets are off.

Comment: static_cast works "too" right and expected to be UB)

Comment: Can you make a whole sentence? I don't want to guess what you are trying to express.

Comment: Whole sentences here: Where standard says that applying static_cast may result in UB? I doubt that **static**_cast may result in UB, because all computation most likely happens in compile time (and therefore compiler can generate either warning or error)

Comment: You can convert from void* to any pointer type using static_cast. Of course, invoking functions on the resulting pointer will invoke UB unless it really points at an object of the according type.

Comment: @UlrickEckhardt ITYM "You can convert from `void *` to any object pointer type using static_cast"

Comment: You're right, Matt, a static_cast won't convert to a function pointer type or remove cv-qualifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of one way this can be done is described in the [Itanium ABI](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/cxxabi-1.83.html#member-pointers) - if you're interested in how the C++ class model can be implemented I highly recommend reading that whole document.

When you convert from a pointer-to-derived-member-function to pointer-to-base-member-function the compiler knows that when you call it `this` will point to base not derived. So it needs to make sure that the first thing it does is to modify `this` back from base* to derived*. It can either do this by inventing a shim function which modifies `this` and jumps to the real function, or by just storing the offset along with the pointer and using it at the call site (which is what the reference above describes). Or I'm sure there are other ways.

(`static_cast` is not just a compile time operation; quite often it has to do real work at runtime.)